# Keep app running under lockscreen in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8.1

It seems that

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

is no longer available in Windows Phone 8.1 (non-Silverlight). Is there a way to get app running under lock screen like playing audio but for our own purpose like performing time consuming image, video processing in the background?

From official documentation such as https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642090.aspx, I sort of guess that from 8.1 running stuffs under lock screen is privilege of Microsoft's stock apps and that developers are limited to whatever they are supplying. For e.g. third party apps can only playing audio via MediaPlayer API and download/upload files via Background transfer in background. I could guess the intention is to rein rogue apps and conserve battery; but this forces genuine apps and users to keep the screen on and this drains battery even more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible to run your app (main part) under lockscreen. As soon as lockscreen is engaged, your app will be suspended ([see more at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464925.aspx)).

If you want to prevent from auto-lockscreen you can use [DisplayRequest class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241816.aspx).

Note that when your app perform a long running operatin (also probably consuming battery) the user should have possiblity to cancel/monitor the process.

As for running code in background in WinRT it is possible:

- for audio take a look at [Background audio at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396),
- take a look at [Background Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) - which allow to run code in the background in various cases and conditions,
- for transferring files - [Background Transfer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452979.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the information. It confirms my guess. So I guess for now I have to stick with battery draining `DisplayRequest` then; hopefully, not too much if the brightness is set at lowest level. It is now transparent to me why people deemed Windows Phone was plagued with design flaws. Background tasks appears to be the closest thing I am looking for; but they "cannot" be run under lock screen either (due to extremely limited constraints imposed).

Comment: @VuAnHoa Background task can be run under lock screen, they can run even your has been closed. Though they have some limits and need some conditions to be met.